# Perform selector with a callback = concurrency?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa, methods, concurrency

I'm having a tiny question on a situation I'm facing.
I have 2 methods :

```
- (void)firstSelector {
    [self launchAsyncTask];
    ... do some work for a long time (10secs) ...
}

- (void)asyncTaskFinished {
    ... some work after 5secs of async task ...
}
```

`firstSelector` performs `launchAsyncTask` which is just a background task that has a callback called `asyncTaskFinished`.
Assuming that `firstSelector` runs for a certain time after launching the async task (let's say 10 seconds), and that the async task runs for 5 seconds, will there be a concurrency problem?

How does this work under the hood?
Will `asyncTaskFinished` be executed after `firstSelector`, or `firstSelector` will be paused to run `asyncTaskFinished`?

Is there a link with run loops? Are methods added to a queue and then executed as I call them?

I'm lost :)

Thank you.

Comment: Have you read the documentation http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html ? I believe it explains everything until you have any specific question.

Comment: I understand that my callback is queued using the main thread run loop, but what about firstSelector? I perform it using the standard "[self firstSelector];". It is also queued this way?

Comment: The 'callbacks' are usually fired in the same thread as the main 'operation', it might be any thread, not only the main. As you have no code to discuss, that is in general possible that `firstSelector` is called from detached thread and `launchAsyncTask` creates another background thread as well. Or it might be the same main/detached thread for both of them, or one of them is at main and another at detached threads. You might also decide to always fire the callback on the main thread. That is all driven by design and always needs to be well documented, as each scenario is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Async tasks run asynchronously which do not run on the main run loop while UI runs on the main loop. Have a look at the [Concurrency Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide.pdf).

So here in your case, you are not really sure about how long the sync time is going to take. You are assuming that it might take 10 sec but it is not completely sure. So, in this case you will need to work with block or find a way to trigger the asyncTaskFinished function when the async task completed on the main thread. You could define a simple block callbacks and then trigger the function when the async task finishes.

If you use GCD for async task, it becomes really easy. You would do just this much;

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        [self runMyAsyncTask];
        // trigger the main completion handler when this completed
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self asyncTaskFinished];
        });
    });
```

If you use NSThread for concurrency you could use performSelector:onThread: to trigger the completion selector when the async task finishes. For a simple case, I will show you to implement a callback handler. You could create a function like this to trigger the async task,

```
-(void)launchAsyncTaskWithCompletionHandler:(void(^)(void))completionHandler{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        [self runMyAsyncTask];
        // trigger the main completion handler when this completed
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            completionHandler();
        });
    });
}
```

And calling this is relatively simple;

```
[self launchAsyncTaskWithCompletionHandler:^{
        [self asyncTaskFinished];
    }];
```

This is easy to understand and makes your code much clearer. Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you. I understand what you wrote and already know these concepts. The question I'm having happens when a method A runs and a callback B from another entity is called on the same thread (but method A isn't finished yet). If both methods are queued using run loops, there's no problem (and I think it's the case with the callback since I know that -performSelector... uses the run loop).

Comment: But in the case where A is not queued (and this is where I have no idea on what happens under the hood with cocoa when using [self methodA];), it rises a question (A is executing, and B will be performed, the question is when and how since A is not in a queue).

Comment: @Nicolas Please have a look at the `Queuing Tasks for Dispatch` section of the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html It has a good and short explanation of available serial/concurrent queues.

Answer (score 0):

A thread's run loop executes tasks from its input sources in a sequential (non-concurrent) fashion.  Therefore, you do not need to worry as long as `firstSelector` and `asyncTaskFinished` are executed in the same run loop.  This will depend on the callback semantics.  You may need to use something like `performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:` to ensure the asynchronous callback function is executed in the correct thread.